# Can modern printers be used without drivers?

Tags: printing

I was thinking of buying Epson's ET-2720 printer-with-scanner, but I don't want
to install any unfree software.  I couldn't find the printer on
openprinting.org.  But I also see that CUPS is "deprecating" support for
printer drivers, because of IPP and standard file formats

https://github.com/apple/cups/issues/5270

Does this mean that I don't need a driver?  There clearly are drivers; why do
they exist if they are not needed?

Answer (score 2):

Modern (and not-so-modern) printers can be used without drivers, thanks to a number of “driverless” protocols such as [AirPrint](https://wiki.debian.org/CUPSAirPrint) and [IPP Everywhere](https://wiki.debian.org/CUPSIPPEverywhere) (and arguably before that, widely-supported protocols such as PostScript and PCL, sometimes with some local configuration *via* PPDs etc.).

The ET-2720 supports AirPrint so it should work out of the box — connect it to your network, and your desktop environment should detect it and allow you to print to it.

As you pointed out, technically this requires drivers on the client, the difference is that they are not printer-specific and they are provided as standard by CUPS, which many Unix-style systems rely on for printing. Printer-specific drivers are typically used for other features, including ink level monitoring, various scanning features, as well as basic printing support on proprietary operating systems.